# how can I fetch a data created by javascript calculation

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

There is a site, http://www.swadpia.co.kr/goods/goods_view/CNC1000/GNC1001

In this site, There are many options like size, colors, etc..
and when I select a option, total price changes

I think that price is generated by javascript.
How can I fetch that data with python?
I want to scrapy all total price with many options.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from pprint import pprint

url = "http://www.swadpia.co.kr/estimate/estimate_goods/json_data"
data = json.load(urlopen(url))

for key, value in data.items():
    pprint("Key:")
    pprint(key)
```

This will make a screen output

```
'Key:'
'paper_kind'
'Key:'
'paper_type'
'Key:'
'paper_type_print'
'Key:'
'paper_info'
'Key:'
'size_info'
'Key:'
'print_info1'
'Key:'
'print_info2'
'Key:'
'print_info3'
'Key:'
'print_info4'
```

Now you have all key,value pairs.

Or something like this

```
url = "http://www.swadpia.co.kr/estimate/estimate_goods/json_data"
data = json.load(urlopen(url))

print (type(data))

for key in data:
    if (key == 'paper_kind'):
        print ("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, data[key]))
```

Than you got

```
<class 'dict'>
key: paper_kind , value: [{'common_code': 'PKD10', 'code_name': '일반지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD20', 'code_name': '고급지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD30', 'code_name': '특수지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD40', 'code_name': '(펄)지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD50', 'code_name': '하드커버지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD60', 'code_name': '카드/투명명함'}, {'common_code': 'PKD70', 'code_name': '스티커'}, {'common_code': 'PKD71', 'code_name': '스티커 롤'}, {'common_code': 'PKD80', 'code_name': '판지'}, {'common_code': 'PKD90', 'code_name': 'NCR'}, {'common_code': 'PKD91', 'code_name': '플라스틱&비닐'}]
```

Comment: but If I want to fetch a data with size 60 * 60 and amount 500, how can I use this json_data?

Comment: Hey,try to expain what you realy want.You can print data and than you have 60*60*500.You want to see attributes?

Comment: OK, I want a price of this page with default options. It is 4,620, how can I find that price with json_data?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the data you want in this JSON file.

[`http://www.swadpia.co.kr/estimate/estimate_goods/json_data`](http://www.swadpia.co.kr/estimate/estimate_goods/json_data)

Comment: oh, how can you find that data? awesome!

Comment: but If I want to fetch a data with size 86 * 52 and amount 500, how can I use this json_data?